# How do I ignore whitespace in the file name when calling \includegraphics?

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

I'd like my latex code to be more organised with indents so it's easier to read. Is there any way to ignore the whitespace in the file name?
Here's what I'd like to do:

```
\includegraphics[lots, of, options, set, here]{
   my_very_long_and_decriptive_file_name.eps
}
```

Comment: works fine for me. Is your latex up-to-date?

Comment: it should work as it is, but as always you can (and should) add `%` to ends of lines to comment them out.

Comment: There is no whitespace in your file name.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Adding `%` to the end of the first and second lines worked. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using the texlive package supplied by Ubuntu 18.04. So, it's version 2017.